# webpack: "[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module" - But I AM using import！

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack, es6-modules

I'm trying to generate an npm package with webpack, which will contain ES6-level JavaScript (generated from TypeScript), and will use the ES6 module format as well, without transpiling down to ES5 and CommonJS. (Eventually I'd like to have ES5/CommonJS in the package too, in addition to the ES6 code.)

I'm getting this error when I try to run `webpack`:

> [webpack-cli] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/.../webpack.config.mjs

As you can see, however, I AM using `import` in my `webpack.config.mjs` file, which looks like this:

```
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from 'clean-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

export default {
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  ...
```

I'm using node v14.15.1, which is supposed to support ES6 module generation. My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Blah, blah, blah",
  "type": "module",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --output-module",
    "prepack": "npm run build",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "nyc --reporter=html mocha --require ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "test-dev": "mocha --require ts-node/register -w --watch-extensions ts src/**/*.spec.ts"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "webpack": "^5.10.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
    ...
```

I've tried all sorts of variations on the above: `main` instead of `module`, `main` along with `module`, with the same or different file names (such as `"module": "dist/index.esm.js"`). I've tried taking away the webpack `--output-module` option, or using the `--experiments-output-module` option.

I've found lots of posts concerning `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM`, but none dealing specifically with what I'm trying to do here with webpack. Even for other related issues there seems to be lots of frustration but few answers.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by migrating to `typescript` type of files and approach. Suprisingly enough it works:

`package.json`

```
{ 
   ...
   "type": "module",
   ...
}
```

`babel.config.ts`

```
export default api => {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ['...'],
    plugins: ['...'],
    env: { '...': '...' },
  }
}
```

`webpack.common.ts`

```
import { common } from './webpack.common'
import webpack from 'webpack'
...

export default {
  entry: {
    '...': '...',
  },
  output: {
    '...': '...',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    '...': '...',
                  },
                ],
                '@babel/preset-react',
                '@babel/typescript',
              ],
              plugins: [
                ['babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore', {}],
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      '...'
    ],
  },
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "...": "..."
  },
  "include": ["..."],
  "exclude": ["..."],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": ["..."]
  },
  "defaultSeverity": "..."
}
```

Comment: I'd practically forgotten about this question, and had given up, using a `webpack.config.cjs` file instead. I had no idea you could even use a `webpack.config.ts` file -- I'll definitely have to give that a shot. Even without having tried this yet, I'll give you a presumptive up-vote :)

Comment: For me it works. I was inspired by code that I saw at my work. But for some reasons they did not go so far. I migrated even `babel.config.ts` to typescript. Of course the result depends on compiler-transpiler settings.